# Prepending this data instead of appending

Tags: javascript

I have to move a specific table row before the first row on the table.
the code below always append the specific table row at the end of the table. I need to prepend it on top on  a single click.

```
rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i], rows[i + rows[i]]);
```

do you have any solutions? I am new on this so I am hoping you could help.
thanks.

Comment: Did you try to use prepend() instead of insertBefore()?, see also MDN. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/prepend

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Node.insertBefore()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)

> The Node.insertBefore() method inserts a node before the reference node as a child of a specified parent node.

So, just select the current first child node of the parent, and the new row will be inserted before it, at the very top:

```
const parentNode = rows[i].parentNode;
parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i], parentNode.childNodes[0]);
```